# remove line from my dropdownlist using angularjs mvc 5

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I am creating a web app in which i am updating my records with dropdownlist

i am fetching the records with angularjs `controller` but unfortunately one blank line is being added in my dropdownlist at the begining of my dropdownlist

```
<select ng-model="mdupm" ng-options="o.empname as o.empname for o in getpm" class="form-control"></select>
```

this is how my dropdownlist look like

what i need to do here, to remove an blank line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<option value="" style="display: none"></option>` as a filler

```
<select ng-model="mdupm" ng-options="o.empname as o.empname for o in getpm" ng-change="(o)" class="form-control">
  <option value="" style="display: none"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: space has been removed but still dropddown list is blank

Answer (score 0):

Just add this `<option value="" ng-show="false"></option>` in select.
You commented "space has been removed but still dropddown list is blank". Is there anything else?

```
<select ng-model="mdupm" ng-options="o.empname as o.empname for o in getpm" class="form-control" >
 <option value="" ng-show="false"></option>
```

Comment: still there is an extra blank line

Comment: okay, then add one jsfiddle/plunker of your code. So, I will verify the issue.